# lady sayadev, saygi u ba khin goenka lineage vipassan

Tags: vipassana

In the above-titled lineage of vipassana, it is said that as soon as there is contact through the sensory bases, sensations are produced on the body.

Why and how does this happen?

And, what are the type of sensations arising on physical body -- for example, tingling, etc., etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Goenka tradition explains it, but Contact(Passa) means the union of form,sense & sense consciousness. That always causes feeling(Vedana) to arise according to Paticca-samuppada(dependant arising).

Comment: i am in search of the explanation of reason as to why and due to what factors the things arise in dependant origination chain. however your answer at least gave me way where to search

Comment: @AnchalKate http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/n_r/paticca_samuppaada.htm

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille Bodily sensations and vedana are two different things. :) Though in both cases contact is the reason why we experience them both in the first place.

Comment: @Medhiṇī I'm not sure what you mean by "bodily sensations" if it's not Vedana.  Why not mention the Pali word and we can discuss if there is a difference?

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille It's not one word. Tingling is a bodily sensation, pressure is a bodily sensation, itching, vibrating, pricking, pulling, tearing ... these are all bodily sensations. And they can be either pleasant or unpleasant (and that is vedana). Hope this makes things a bit more clear. :)

Comment: @Medhiṇī the reason why you couldn't tell the Pali word is because there is none that refers to Paramattha Dhamma. :) The so called "bodily sensations" you listed are just a combination of earth, water, fire, air elements associated with Vedana(feeling).

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille Yeah, later on I thought that to make it short I could call it rupa. Anyway, it is not the same as vedana. See also my explanation to the op. :)

Comment: @Medhiṇī "Bodily sensations" include both Rupa and Vedana and there is no sensation without Vedana so this answer holds true either way ;)

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille Lol... you were right saying that vedana is always present, basically in every experience. I was just pointing out that the op was about bodily sensations. And I don't agree with you there that bodily sensations include vedana. They are rupa which is a category on its own. On the other hand, we might both use the term 'bodily sensations' differently. Maybe for you that term refers to the mix of rupa and vedana where I make a further distinction. Communication is always tricky. :)

Comment: @Medhiṇī are you  saying there are sensations without Vedana?

Comment: Bodily Sensation = bodily sensory experience. Every bodily sensory experience includes Rupa, Vedana, Sanna, Sankhara, Vinnana. Otherwise it wouldn't be called Panchaskhanda ;)

Comment: No, I'm not saying that there are sensations (the mix) without vedana. I never had an experience which didn't include vedana. I'm saying that bodily sensations are of the rupa category (air, earth, water, fire ...) plus, next to those also arises vedana. Basically every mundane experience consists of 5 categories. But itching fi. is not an unpleasant feeling. It is mostly air element (plus the other rupa). For some it comes with an unpleasant feeling, for others with pleasant feeling. Some might not even recognise it (sanna), others immediately. Not everyone reacts (sankhara). and so on. :)

Comment: Itching is an irritation. That's usually unpleasant. Even if it is neutral, it's still adukkhama- sukha vedana. Sanna, Sankhara, Vinnana are also there in some form. All 5 arise together. They do not arise one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sankha said, there are a few things necessary to come to an experience of sensations. Contact is when those factors come together.
So far, so good.

Bodily sensations are a very rich study object, imho.
There is at least always present: the earth element (hard, soft and so on), the wind element, the fire element and the water element. Those four (plus four others) form the mix of matter that is always there when it comes to material elements. But that mix is variable, meaning that the amount of earth element is not always the same, same goes, of course, for all the other elements.

Let's say you experience a tingling sensation. If you unpack this you'll find that in that 'mix of matter' there is a lot of wind element present. If it is a sharp, cold tingling sensation then there is not a lot of fire element present. If the tingling is warm and smooth, there will be more fire element. When you experience a very dense sensation, there will probably a lot of earth element there and less wind element. And so on.

Like with the mind states matter also comes and goes. It has, like the mind, its causes and conditions.
Depending on how precise you want to know what's going on the Paticca Samuppada might not be enough. You should also dive into the 'Compendium of Matter' and the 'Compendium of Conditionality' (both are part of the Abhidhamma Sangaha).

Further, as Sankha states, every experience contains also an affect, the way a sensation feels. Bodily sensations can be experienced as pleasant or unpleasant; mind states can be experienced as pleasant, unpleasant or neutral.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes it really helps, i was a bit interested to know ,what what bodily  sensations are experienced by a vipassana practitioner

Answer (score 0):

If by 'why', you are asking in a physiological sense then its because our body is not a static mass of matter. It's because of Annicca i.e. there is a continous activity going on even on the most superficial level of your skin. During Vipassana you concentrate on the small region which leads to increased awareness of such activity on your skin, depending on the activity you might feel different sensations may it be tingiling or itching etc. So the sensations is manifestation of Annicca, and that is the wisdom you have to attain through Vipassana, to realise this very nature of Annicca.

If your question pertains to physics of it like, how does this happen? It happens in a way like, the activity on your skin produces related response on the nerve endings near the skin, these nerve endings take the signal to the brain and related consciousness is produced.

And the types of sensations are told by S.N Goenka like tingling, irritating, prickling, pleasent or unpleasent.